# How can i limit an user account to impersonate only some target service accounts?

Tags: google-cloud-iam

I have an user account that want to impersonate some service accounts at same project. I know I can assign `Service Account Token Creator` role to this user account to enable impersonate.

But the problem is that the user account can impersonate any service accounts at same project. How can I limit an user account that can only impersonate only some target service accounts?

I also look up IAM condition but it seems that it doesn't support service account resource type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the IAM policy bindings for the service account instead of the project.

> Service accounts are also resources that can have their own allow
> policies. As a result, you can let other principals access a service
> account by granting them a role on the service account, or on one of
> the service account's parent resources. For example, to let a user
> impersonate a service account, you could grant the user the Service
> Account User role (roles/iam.serviceAccountUser) on the service
> account.

Review this [link](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-account-overview#service-accounts-resources) and this [link](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/iam/service-accounts/add-iam-policy-binding).

Comment: I solved my problem. Thanks!